# Mean Function Parameters

Tags: r, function, mean

Does anyone know the parameters that the default 'mean' function takes in R?

We're looking to write a variation of the function to use in aggregate and need to know exactly what is expected.

Thanks folks.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You can call the function description (including parameters) by `?mean`.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  Instead of asking how to write an overloaded function, please tell us the desired result, as it's probable that `aggregate` or some `plyr` tool already does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the answer using `?mean` to search local help and `??mean` to search the global help.

*Most probable answer you are looking for:*

```
mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)
```

Comment: Hi, I think that is what we're looking for. Cheers.